# Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am getting the error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1. Parameter name: dueTime' when attempting to start a timer.

Here is the code using Visual C#:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timerSync;
private double intervalInSeconds = 3600000d; //updated externally

public static void Initialize()
{
    timerSync = new Timer();
    timerSync.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalInSeconds).TotalMilliseconds;
    timerSync.Elapsed += TimerSync_Elapsed;
    timerSync.Start(); //exception is thrown here...
}

private static void TimerSync_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) { }
```

**What I've tried so far**

The `Interval` property is of type double, and the resulting value is within range. If I manually set the interval to a lower value like 3600 the exception is not thrown. However, in my application context,  **I don't have much control** over the Interval value as it is updated from a web service.

I've thought of casting the value to type int32 or int64. Any suggestions? How do I go about this.

Comment: So you really want to have one timer event every 40 days?

Comment: Thank you. Remember `Interval` is of type double. 40 days or not, the property accepts the value. Please note I obtain a variable (in secs format) from a web service, convert it to milliseconds then set it to the Timer Interval property. I therefore have no control over the size of the value returned.

Comment: You just look at the surface of things. Just because its a double does not mean it must work with any value allowed in that range. It could change by context (different Plattform that allow different values for example, Timers are mostly an OS thing). Said that if your system should allow intervals in that range Timers are the wrong feature to look at. The plattform this runs on should have a scheduler in some form that should be way more fitting. It would even surface restarting the system.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval) states that `Interval` must be less or equal to `In32.MaxValue`.

`TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600000d).TotalMilliseconds` is `3.600.000.000` which is higher than `Int32.MaxValue` = `2.147.483.647`

Comment: Then it remains I would have to cast the value to Int32 `int interval = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalInSeconds).TotalMilliseconds);`?

Comment: No, this will give you an `OverflowException`

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeSpan.Duration()` to get the absolute value of the timespan.

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalInSeconds).Duration().TotalMilliseconds
```